# Karma Jasmine unit testing with Angular 4 is caching

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I comment out code in a spec file and it is still failing my test.

1. why is it like this?
2. what can I do about this ,  edit karma config file with something????

So here is a snippet of what I commented out

```
it('Should find trackerId in the session tracker slider panel', () => {
    let sessionTrackerfixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrackerFormTemplateComponent);
    let sessionTrackerapp = sessionTrackerfixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    sessionTrackerapp.model.session = '1234567890-1-1';
    sessionTrackerfixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = sessionTrackerfixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.session').textContent).toContain('1234567890-1-1');
});
```

It still shows up

```
TrackerFormTemplateComponent Should find trackerId in the session tracker slider panel
```